# 0 value doesn't appear using Google Apps Script Simple Mail Merge

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailmerge

During the use of the following [script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge), if in a cell of one the columns that I indicated in the email template, is present "0" as a value, it doesn't appear in the final emails sent.

It is replaced by an empty string as if the cell were empty.

I suppose the issue is in that statement:

```
// Replace variables from the template with the actual values from the data object.
// If no value is available, replace with the empty string.
for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; ++i) {
// normalizeHeader ignores ${"} so we can call it directly here.
var variableData = data[normalizeHeader(templateVars[i])];
email = email.replace(templateVars[i], variableData || "");
}
```

but if I deleate the boolean symbol and I leave only "variableData" the problem moves on the empty cells (0 value in the sent emails is displayed but the empty cells are returned as "undefined" in the email text).

I hope someone can help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to JavaScript, where 0, `''`, `""`, `null`, and `undefined` all mean `false`-y.

The issue you have is that the logical OR performed by `||` uses a non-strict equality comparison, so when `variableData` is 0 it is type-converted to `false` (along with the desired conversions of `null` and `undefined`) and the alternate substitution of `""` is selected.

To resolve the issue, you will need to perform a more rigorous check of the value of `variableData` prior to replacing with it.

For example, a ternary operator can be used:

```
var variableData = ...
variableData = (!variableData && variableData !== 0) ? "" : variableData
```

This will replace with `""` for the other `false`-y values but allow replacing with the numeric value `0`. Also note that `String(0)` is truthy, so if you return your found variables as a string, the short circuit operator should yield the desired results.

Comment: Thank you!! I tried your statement and it works in my case. Sorry if my question was too trivial. I'm just a beginner.